# Validation not working for small case alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written following jquery for allowing only capital and small alphabets to a textbox

```
$(".only-alphabets").keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 &&
        (e.which < 65 || e.which > 90) && (e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)
      ) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
```

Now it works fine for A to Z but works only for a to i in small case. 
Please help !!!

Comment: `(e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)` change this to `(e.which < 96 || e.which > 122)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".only-alphabets").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 &&
    (e.which < 65 || e.which > 90) && (e.which < 96 || e.which > 122)
  ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='only-alphabets'>
```

ASCII code for lower case is from a-96 to z-122

Answer (score 2):

You use regular expression:

```js
$("#myTextBox").on("input", function(){
  var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
  if($(this).val().match(regexp)){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(regexp,'') );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
```